# Not able to run Meteor application in Docker container because of couldn't run ps ax error

Tags: node.js, meteor, docker

I created a Docker image from a Dockerfile to run a sample Meteor application. My Dockerfile is as follows.

```
FROM node:0.10.30

RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
RUN npm install -g meteorite

RUN cd /tmp && npm install libxmljs exec-sync path
RUN mkdir -p /home/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /home/app/

ADD src/ /home/app/

WORKDIR /home/app

ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
```

My code uses 3 npm packages libxmljs, exec-sync and path which all got installed successfully. The Meteor application code and .meteor folder are copied to `/home/app` inside the docker image. But when I try to run the Meteor application, I get the following error.

```
sudo docker run -t -i 46630d0dc02e meteor
[[[[[ ~home/app ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Starting MongoDB... -
/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Couldn't run ps ax: {"killed":false,"code":127,"signal":null}; Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: ps: not found
    at Object.Future.wait (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at findMongoPids (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-mongo.js:89:14)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-mongo.js:119:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-mongo.js:234:5)
    at launchMongo (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-mongo.js:496:7)
    at _.extend._startOrRestart (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-mongo.js:585:19)
    at _.extend.start (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-mongo.js:551:10)
    at _.extend.start (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-all.js:131:24)
    at Object.exports.run (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-all.js:272:10)
    at main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/commands.js:210:17)
    at /.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/main.js:949:23
    - - - - -

    at /.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-mongo.js:59:22
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:651:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:968:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I would greatly appreciate if anybody could explain the reason for the error and suggest a solution or workaround for running meteor application in docker container.

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour a few times recently, I don't know what's causing it but for some reason `/bin` gets removed from the `$PATH`. You can re-add it by doing an `export PATH=$PATH:/bin`. It sounds like this could be a docker bug, I would upgrade your version of docker to the latest to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node` image dosen't have `ps` command.

```
$ docker run -t -i node:0.10.30 bash
root@1d5c5e3ec748:/# ps
bash: ps: command not found
root@f1d530730c37:/# find / -name ps -type f
root@f1d530730c37:/#
```

Use another base image which have `ps command` or install `ps` command on your image by adding `RUN` directive to your Dockerfile like below.

```
FROM node:0.10.30

# Install ps command
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install procps

RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
RUN npm install -g meteorite

RUN cd /tmp && npm install libxmljs exec-sync path
RUN mkdir -p /home/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /home/app/

ADD src/ /home/app/

WORKDIR /home/app

ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
```

I tested it, and it works fine.

```
$ docker run -t -i nacyot/meteor bash
root@0b56bf009532:/home/app/test# meteor create test
root@0b56bf009532:/home/app/test# cd test
root@0b56bf009532:/home/app/test# meteor 
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
root@0b56bf009532:/home/app/test# meteor
[[[[[ ~home/app/test ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Started your app.   

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: I could run the meteor application inside docker container now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [phusion/passenger-docker](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker). It is advertised to be a ready2use docker image for Meteor apps.